# Xilinx Line <read_line> has not enough elements for target <input_b> for the file with more than one line

Tags: vhdl, io, process

I have a file each line of which includes two 9 bits inputs. Here is an example of this file:

**input_vectors.txt:**

```
001111000 001100000
001111000 001100000
001111000 001100000
001111000 001100000
```

I want to simply read the inputs of each line and assign them as the inputs to an adder. The signals **input_a_fp** and **input_b_fp** are connected to the inputs of the adder and I assign the inputs read from the file to these signals. When I declare just one line in the file above, everything is fine and the result of the adder is ok. But, for more than one line, I get the error:

> Line <**read_line**> has not enough elements for target <**input_b**>

I searched and found that this error can be fixed by adding the line: `exit when endfile (file_input_vectors);` before the read function and after the readline function. I have already added this line but the error appears again when the file includes more than one line.

The code for reading the file is as below:

```
process
    --variable declaration
    variable read_line : line;
    variable write_line: line;

variable input_a     : std_logic_vector(8 downto 0);
variable input_b     : std_logic_vector(8 downto 0);

variable space_char: character;

--process definition
begin
        if input_clk'event and input_clk = '1' then

         file_open(file_input_vectors, "input_vectors.txt",  read_mode);

         while (not endfile(file_input_vectors)) loop
                --read a line and its components --> input_a input_b
                readline(file_input_vectors, read_line); 
                exit when endfile (file_input_vectors);

                read(read_line, input_a);
                read(read_line, space_char);
                read(read_line, input_b);

                input_a_fp <= input_a;
                input_b_fp <= input_b;

        end loop;

        file_close(file_input_vectors);

    end if;
end process;
```

Comment: The error message appears to be from XST (Xilinx Synthesis Technology, a synthesis tool used by ISE). See [XST - "ERROR:Xst:1923 - Line has not enough elements for target"](https://www.xilinx.com/support/answers/22376.html). TEXTIO is not supported for synthesis other than in an impure function providing initial values for signals, variables or expressions for constants. TEXTIO in a process statement wouldn't be supported for synthesis.

Comment: I want to implement an adder which reads a matrix of two 8bit inputs and adds them. Since vhdl or verilog do not support 2D vectors as inputs and outputs, I wanted to use file for reading the inputs and writing the outputs,

Comment: Are you intending to synthesis or simulate? XST does support multi-dimensional array types of to 3 dimensions (UG627,  Ch 14. XST VHDL Language Support, VHDL Data Types, see Coding Example Two). Simulators would have no problem. Synthesized logic in an FPGA can't use TEXTIO to perform File READ.

Comment: Yes, I want to synthesize first because I want to check different parameters like utilization. So, the problem is that I cannot use file reading during synthesis

Comment: During synthesis (elaboration, default expressions in signal or variable or value expression in constant declarations) or after implementation (in silicon)?

Comment: See [Xilinx Line <read_line> has not enough elements for target <input_b> for the file with more than one line](https://forums.xilinx.com/t5/Synthesis/Xilinx-Line-lt-read-line-gt-has-not-enough-elements-for-target/m-p/958667).

Comment: @user8352: Thanks for your help. File I/O cannot be used in synthesis as you said. The link you referred to was my own post.

Comment: @user8352: As far as I know, there are 3 steps: synthesis, implement, and place and route. I should go through these steps in Xilinx ISE to be able to use the report it gives about important parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert by any means, but my first guess is that you have a compatibility issue with regard to line endings between your text editor and your simulator.

I just did a quick survey of Std.Textio implementations on the web, and found that they are not consistent in this regard. Indeed, the standard itself is rather vague on this topic.

I think that what is happening is that your text editor is putting double character line endings (i.e., either CRLF or LFCR) in the file, but your simulator is looking for single characters (i.e., just CR or just LF). When it sees two characters, it interprets that as an empty line, which is what causes the message that you see.

I would recommend:

- Do a binary dump of your text file to see what kind of line endings are actually there.
- Create a file with just single-character line endings (by whatever means necessary).

Comment: Great point, thanks. I checked it with a hex editor. I should normally get such a thing for the first two lines:
048048049049049049048048048032048048049049048048048048048010048048049049049049048048048032048048049049048048048048048
but my editor shows other strange binaries as well. Is the problem with the hex editor or he text editor?

Comment: Really, a "hex editor" that displays in decimal? In any case, it looks like you have just a single LF in there, so perhaps my theory is wrong.

Comment: I generated this binary by myself but the hex editor has a different result. Some other strange binaries

Comment: @user8352: Thanks for jumping in here, and I appreciate your much better answer. However, I still don't understand why the OP's space_char read would be consuming anything other than the space. Isn't the space the first character in the buffer after the `read(read_line, input_a)`? (I agree that explicitly reading the space is unnecessary, because the  `read(read_line, input_b)` would skip that space anyway.)

Comment: @user8352: OK, thanks. So it is a library bug, just not the bug I thought it was. I was misled by the description that it worked for one line, but not for multiple lines.

Comment: VHDL is non-specific about ASCII file format line endings because it expects an implementations ReadLine to remove any end of line formatting characters.   A tool that does not remove them is non-1076 compliant